# custom hyper-ledger fabric app with web application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to create custom hyperledger fabric app with following steps

1. Download sample code, customized the code configuration for 1
   channel, 1 org, 3 peers (what files to edit? how to edit?)
2. generate business network archive using hyperledger composer.
3. Deploy business network archive to hyperledger fabric
4. generate web angular 4  application

Please share some links and content for each step

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) will guide you in generating and deploying a business network archive using composer. It also covers about generating a sample angular app.

For #1 you can first go through [build your first network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) tutorial. It will help you build up concepts for setting up a simple fabric network. This tutorial builds on [fabric samples](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/samples.html). In your case, you can use "basic-network" sample for a single org and single channel. You'll need to modify "crypto-config.yaml" and "docker-compose.yml" file to add additional peers into the organization.